# If $ab > 1$, can $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ be an integer?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, integers

I've been thinking about this positive fraction where $a,b$ are positive integers and whether it can be an integer for $ab > 1$:

$$\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$$

Clearly, if $a=1, b=1$, then:

$$\frac{3^1-2^1}{2^2 - 3^1} = 1$$

Is there any other value of $a,b$ that results in a positive integer?

I am interested in either finding a solution where $ab > 1$ and it is a positive integer or an approach to show that no such integer exists.

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for an alternative way to show that there are no nontrivial $1$-cycles.  It seems to me that there might be a much simpler way to show this.  If no integer exists, then this can be used to show that there is no $1$-cycle (if I did not make a mistake in my reasoning).

Comment: Could you include the connection to Collatz problem? i.e how would a solution other than $a=b=1$ lead to a 1-cycle?

Comment: I will post it as a follow up question.  My reasoning may be wrong and I am interested in the answer to this question independent of the collatz conjecture.

Comment: @coffeemath I posted my follow up question here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4067889/48606

Comment: Thanks for the link, @LarryFreeman .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've reminded me of my least favorite fact about the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which is that [it ruins music](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/the-saddest-thing-i-know-about-the-integers/).

We need the denominator to be (relatively) small if it's going to be a divisor of anything. But small values in the denominator are going to be hard, if not impossible, to find, as $a$ increases. Obviously we cannot have $2^x = 3^y$ unless $x = y$. We have $3^2 - 2^3 = 1$ from Catalan's Conjecture, but that's in the wrong order.

But then it gets worse. The generalized/extended Catalan Conjecture suggests that prime powers have a tendency to repel one another as they get larger. For instance, there are exactly five instances below $2^64$ where a pair of prime powers fall between one prime and the next. The pairs of powers are $(8,9)$ as above, $(25,27),(121,125),(2187,2197)$, and $(32761,32768)$.

The smallest positive value of $2^{a+b} - 3^a$ for a given $a$ (as found by varying $b$) isn't technically an increasing function, but the decreases are few and far between. And decreasing from $24062143$ to $5077565$ (for $a = 16,17$) isn't what we're looking for. The only "small" values other than your $a = b = 1$ are $5,7,13,47$ for $a = 3,2,5,4$. None of those give an integer quotient (they are $\frac{19}{5}, \frac{65}{7}, \frac{211}{13}, \frac{665}{47}$), and after that most of the values just get exponentially larger.

Essentially, barring an exception to the extended Catalan Conjecture, which I think would be hugely shocking, you can't get an integer out of this. But, technically, it's an open question.