# Collatz Conjecture: Does it follow that since there is no $1$-cycle, if $ab > 1$, then $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ cannot be an integer?

Tags: solution-verification, exponentiation, integers, collatz-conjecture

For me, one of the most interesting results of the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is that if an $m$-cycle exists, then $m > 68$.  So, there are no non-trivial $1$-cycles, $2$-cycles, ..., up to $68$-cycles.  The details behind this argument can be found in this [paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by Simons & De Weger (2003).

Let:

- $\nu_2(x)$ be the [2-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $x$.
- $u = 3^kt - 1$
- $b = \nu_2(u)$
- $a = \nu_2(\frac{u}{2^b}+1)$

If a $1$-cycle exists, then the maximum value of the cycle is equal to $3^kt - 1$ where $k,t$ are positive integer and the lowest value of the cycle is equal to $2^kt - 1$ characterized by the following:

$$u = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^a\left(\frac{u}{2^b} + 1\right)-1$$

So that:

$$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^a(u+1) = \frac{u}{2^b} + 1$$

And:

$$\frac{u(2^{a+b} - 3^a)}{3^a2^b} = \frac{3^a - 2^a}{3^a}$$

Which reduces to:

$$\frac{u}{2^b} = \frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$$

It seems to me that since no non-trivial $1$-cycle exists, it follows that if $a,b$ are positive integers where $ab > 1$, $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ is not a positive integer.

Here's the argument:

(1) Assume that there exists positive integers $a,b$ with $ab > 1$ such that $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ is an integer.

(2)  Let $x = \frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$

(3)  Let $u = 2^bx$

(4)  Let $k = a$, $t = \left(\frac{1}{2^a}\right)\left(\frac{u}{2^b}+1\right)$ which are both integers.

(5)  So it follows that $u = 3^kt - 1$

(6)  But then we have a contradiction since no $1$-cycle exists.  Therefore, we can reject our assumption at step(1).

Is this argument valid?  Does the result from Simons & De Weger (2003) prove that with the given assumptions, $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ is not an integer?

---

**Edit**:  I added the clarification that $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ cannot be a positive integer.

@rukhin makes a great point.  For positive integers $a=2$ and $b=1$, $\dfrac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a} = -5$

This is correlated with the negative $1$-cycle with $k=1$ and $t=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{-10}{2} + 1\right) = -1$

The standard collatz sequence defined as:

- $T(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}(3x + 1), && \text{if }x\text{ is odd}\\
  \frac{1}{2}x, && \text{if }x\text{ is even}\\
  \end{cases}$
- $T_1(x) = T(x)$
- $T_{c+1}(x) = T(T_c(x))$

So that:

$$-1, -2, -1, \dots$$

Comment: It might be interesting, that the final proof of the non-existence of an integer solution contains two parts. First part: for small $a$ prove it by heuristics (including the observation that the most critical cases are listed in the convergents of the continued fractions of $\log_2(3)$. Second part: for large $a$: show that the difference between $2^{a+b} - 3^a$ are too large to allow a solution (here the "integer" question is no more discussed, as I think to remember; transcendence theory is used).

Comment: Small remark: the $1$-cycle has been disproved by Ray Steiner in 1976 (or 78?); J. Simons has built his work on this basic strategy & finding, explicitely mentioning Steiner's work. Sa far as I remember, the 2-cycle disproof was in the same way. For the more complex m-cycles in general I'd surely say this is based on new ideas of Simons & De Weger.

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, what do you mean by too large to allow a solution? $2^{a+b}-3^a$ is always smaller than $3^a-2^a$

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but you need to go this way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001941/integer-solutions-of-2b-n-1-bmod-left-3n-bmod-2b-n-right-0 and use the fact that $2^{a+b}-3^a>2^a>2^{B_n}$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022134/show-that-2n2-lceil-n-log-23-rceil-3n3n-2n for both cases

Comment: @Collag3n - sorry if this was a misformulation, I just wanted to point out that the papers I've seen used a "larger/smaller-than"-style of argument (from the Baker's formulae and later from Rhin's) and when they were at that point, the question of integral divisibility was out of focus. (This shifting of focus was something I had to learn myself to understand "the hard way"...), If this all is felt as distraction from question I can as well delete my comment. For explanation, on the other hand, I've the small essay http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf

Comment: No, it is ok. When you said too large, I was looking at the fraction where it is the denominator. I was not thinking about the Rhin/Baker development (Which I also used in the link in my Answer). Anyway, Larry is looking for a more simple "alternative way" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067552/if-ab-1-can-frac3a-2a2ab-3a-be-an-integer

Comment: What if a = 2 and b = 1?

Comment: @rukhin Thanks for calling this out.  I meant that it cannot be a positive integer.  I will add this detail in the question.  Collatz conjecture does have negative trivial cycles so it does not exclude the example you present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you start with $n_0=2^kt-1$, apply $a$ times the Collatz function $f(n)=\frac{3n+1}{2}$, than $b$ times the Collatz function $f(n)=\frac{n}{2}$, you can easily see that you end up with $$n=\frac{3^a}{2^{a+b}}n_0+\frac{3^a-2^a}{2^{a+b}}$$
or
$$n\cdot{2^{a+b}}-3^a\cdot n_0=3^a-2^a$$
and in the case of a cycle $n=n_0$
$$n=\frac{3^a-2^a}{2^{a+b}-3^a}$$
Note: $a=k$, the value $a = \nu_2(\frac{u}{2^b}+1)$ you gave is for the next iteration

Now in case of a cycle, it has been shown that (you can find it by noticing that $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{3^a}{2^{a+b}}<1$):
$$a+b=\lceil a\cdot \log_2(3)\rceil $$
So indeed, if there is such an integer $n=\frac{3^a-2^a}{2^{a+b}-3^a}$, it must be part of a 1-cycle, and you can conclude there is none (outside the trivial one), but it would only be valid within the above constraint on $a+b$.

Also notice that the question has already been raised.....by you
[Is this argument valid for showing given integers $n>1$ and $2^m > 3^n$, $(2^m - 3^n) \nmid 3^n - 2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862457/is-this-argument-valid-for-showing-given-integers-n1-and-2m-3n-2m)

Also note that a m-cycle does not mean m successive 1-cycles, so there is no such constraint on $a+b$ within the m-cycle (but in this case you don't have $n=n_0$ or the equation you mentioned)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  My previous question had a hole in the reasoning.  This is an attempt to fix that hole based on a better understanding of the proof by Simon & De Weger.